# The surounding area of an ellipse is black. Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am drawing an ellipse using core graphics in iOS. The area near the corners of the ellipse are black in color. I want it to be clearColor. How do I get about this?

```
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, ellipseFrame);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, ellipseFrame);
```

I am sorry. I don't have enough reputations to add the screenshot of my output.

Comment: please show the code you have used to draw.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the context before you start drawing:

```
CGContextClearRect(context, ellipseFrame);
```

Comment: Should I add this line above my 3 lines?

Comment: In general you always draw from back to front.

Answer (score 1):

If you are  drawing ellipse in drawRect method of UIView subclass,
the area near the corners of the ellipse must be taking the background color of UIView.
Setting its backgroundColor to clearColor should sove the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In UIView or NSView you draw from back to front. 
You can think of the code you write in drawRect: as procedural back to front drawing instructions. 
If you see black corners you probably have a containing view that is isOpaque or need to first do [[NSColor clearColor] fill] before subsequent drawing in drawRect: